# Copying a single worksheet to multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a single sheet from a source Excel workbook into approximately 750 other identically arranged workbooks (they do not have a sheet with the same name).

I found a piece of code which should do this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook

    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination woorkbook

    Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Folder containing the destination workbooks

    folder = "F:\temp\excel\"

    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls", vbNormal)
    While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Wend
End Sub
```

I have copied this into my sheet module and modified the elements I think I need to change, as below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook

    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination workbook

    Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Edit")

    'Folder containing the destination workbooks

    folder = "M:\Employee Information\Peter Young\Msc Project\1 - 181028 - Office First Floor\Test\"

    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls", vbNormal)
    While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Wend
End Sub
```

When I click run I get the Macro dialog box, click run again and the box disappears and nothing happens.

When I run the macro in the source workbook nothing happens.

When I run in one of the destination workbooks, I get a subscript out of range error. (I am using Excel 2013.)

Comment: Best to put your macro in a module.  Also, you are using `Activeworkbook` safer option is to use `thisworkbook` referring to the calling workbook, and referencing the opened workbook, by opening it into an object `Dim w as excel.workbook:set w=workbooks.open("c:\a.xlsx"):w.worksheets("Inspect").range("a1").value=123` like that.

Comment: 1. What does error say? 2. What is the line with error?

Answer (score 1):

When you get the error, press the debug button and check where the error happens... that's the usual way to find out what's happening with your code.

In this case, my best guess is that your files are `.xlsx` and not `.xls` ?

If that's the case, then modify this line accordingly `filename = Dir(folder & "*.xls", vbNormal)`

**EDIT**

To add to your question, and as Nathan pointed out, depending on your code it does matter where you run the macro from, in this case given that `Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Edit")` refers to your `ActiveWorkbook`, then your source should be the `ActiveWorkbook` when running the macro.

Using `ThisWorkbook` is also a solution, but depending what you want to do with your code, not always the ideal one.

There is also the option to name the workbook specifically like: `Workbooks("YourSourceWorkbookName.xlsm").Sheets("Edit")`, and then it doesn't matter where you running your code from (at least in this particular case).

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks like it was the .xlsx issue. Thanks for the additional pointers too, all very helpful.

Comment: The code above seems to be working smoothly, copying the sheet over. Further to this, the sheet contains links to other sheets in the source workbook. I'd like to retain those links, but in the destination workbook. I can do this by manually updating the connections (through data-connections-edit links-change source); but is there a way of adding this to the code so excel does this when it copies the data?